# How to split email with python regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying isolate the value that comes after "+" sign in an email. For example, if I have "something+company@gmail.com", I want to get the value you "company". It seems like the + sign kind of messes up the regex and I don't know where to go from here.

Here is what I wrote using re:

```
re.findall(r'something+(.*?)@',st)
```

Comment: why not use split?

Comment: Which regex string have you tried?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: re.findall(r'something+(.*?)@',st)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/Jv3hGx and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` acts like a special character (a repetition operator) when defining a regular expression. You need `\` to escape it:

```
>>> st = "something+company@gmail.com"
>>> re.findall(r'something\+(.*?)@', st)
["company"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem  with your regexp is that `+` is a special character, meaning "repeat the previous character one or more times", in your case, it would match `g` one time, and then the `(.*?)` would match the literal `+`.

The solution is to escape the `+` by preceding it with a `\`:

```
>>> email = 'something+company@gmail.com'
>>> re.findall(r'something\+(.*?)@', email)
['company']
```

---

Having said that, you don't really need a regular expression here.

Your goal is to get all text between the first `+` and the first `@`, which you can do with:

```
>>> email = 'something+company@gmail.com'
>>> email[email.find('+')+1:email.find('@')]
'company'
```

Note that this code will give unexpected results if there's no `+` or `@`, so you'll probably want to add a check around this (e.g. `if '+' in email: ...`).

In addition, you can actually have quoted `@`s and such in emails, so this is not 100% RFC-compliant. However, last time I checked many MTAs and email clients don't support that anyway, so it's not really something you need to worry about as such.

Comment: what's wrong wtih `email.split("@")[0].split("+")[-1]`?

Comment: Nothing as such @OzgurVatansever. I would consider using `find` more readable, but that's entirely a subjective judgement call.

Comment: yeah email.split("@")[0].split("+")[-1] works but can it be done via re?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer @jake. I don't think that using regexps are a good solution, though. As you've found out they can be hard to understand and debug.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I was just practicing but was so curious. Thanks for your input my man.